# Identify Columns using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a df where the suffix is often the filename.

```
df   apple_filename_fruit.csv  banan_filename_new fruity.csv  test_col
0     0                               26                       4 
1    23                              262                       2
2     23                              2626                     3
```

How should the regex be ammended since nothing prints?

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col.endswith("filename_(\w+)") and "new" in col:
         print(col)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think `endswith` work with regexes; one way to edit your for loop is to use the `re` module, and nest the if statements:

```
for col in df:
    if re.search("filename.*$", col):
        if "new" in col:
            print(col)

banan_filename_new
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `$` for end of string and chain with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m = df.columns.str.contains("filename_.*$") & df.columns.str.contains("new")
print (m)
[False False  True False False]

for c in df.columns[m]:
    print (c)
    banan_filename_new
```

Comment: @asd - It should be, but I can change it by `"filename_.*$"`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `filter` with the `regex` argument.

```
df.filter(regex=r'(?=.*filename)(?=.*new)')



  banan_filename_new
0                  26
1                 262
2                2626
```